# Unable to create correct Mongoid model from JSON

Tags: ruby, json, mongoid, mongoid4

I'm trying to create a Mongoid model from the corresponding JSON structure.

However it does not include the embedded relation *frameworks*.
I'm using Mongoid 4.0. Am I doing something wrong or is this a bug?

If I store any embedded relation via *store_as* under a different name than the default serialization, it works as expected. Also, if I *create* the model in the database from JSON rather than initialize it everything's fine...

*JSON input*

```
{
  "name": "MyName",
  "frameworks": [
    {
      "name": "grails",
      "runtime": "groovy",
      "versions": []
    }
  ]
}
```

*Models*

```
require 'mongoid'

class Vendor
  include Mongoid::Document
    include Mongoid::Attributes::Dynamic

  # fields
  field :name, type: String
  # relations
  embeds_many :frameworks
  # validations
  validates :name, presence: true
  validates :frameworks, presence: true
end

class Framework
  include Mongoid::Document

  embedded_in :vendor

  field :name, type: String
  field :runtime, type: String
  field :versions, type: Array
  # validations
  validates :name, presence: true
  validates :runtime, presence: true
end
```

*Test App*

```
require 'json'
require 'require_relative'
require_relative 'vendor'

begin
  json = JSON.parse(File.read('input.json'))
  @profile = Vendor.new(json)
  puts @profile.inspect
rescue JSON::ParserError => e
  puts "Error: " << e.to_s
end
```

Comment: Send your JSON format as,{"vendor":{
  "name": "MyName",
  "frameworks_attributes": [
    {
      "name": "grails",
      "runtime": "groovy",
      "versions": []
    }
  ]
}}

Comment: I must not do this, the JSON is fixed.

Comment: where is your create method where it stores into the database!!!

Comment: I don't want to store it in the DB at this time, but only create a valid Mongoid model from it via `@profile = Vendor.new(json)`